# How can I detect face using HOG features and SVM classifier

Tags: python, svm, face-detection

I have face dataset and want to detect faces inside images. I used the face detector implemented in python dlib library that uses HOG features and linear SVM as the following code:

```
hogFaceDetector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
faceRects = hogFaceDetector(frameDlibHogSmall, 0)
for faceRect in faceRects:
    x1 = faceRect.left()
    y1 = faceRect.top()
    x2 = faceRect.right()
    y2 = faceRect.bottom()
```

The above code works correctly, but I want the source code of it. How can I get the source code where the hog features can be detected and classified step by step. Can anyone please help me?